# Using radon function to perform slant stack in MatLab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to generate slant stack transform curves for some data using inbuilt radon function in Matlab but I am getting different results.

In theory Radon transform is supposed to be a generalized case of slant stacking .

[Algorithm for slant stack](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/data/media/public/sep/prof/iei/slnt/paper_html/node14.html)

pattern of expected result

[image]

results obtained from radon

[image]

what mistake could i be making here ?

Comment: only using inbuilt radon function, no extra code.regarding sample data : http://postimg.org/image/t3z95xs4p/

Comment: From where does your "expected" result come from? What settings were used to create that image? (range of theta, for example, scaling in the display of the output image).

Comment: the algorithm used to create those results has been mentioned in the given link.i was more concerned about the output pattern which is different in both cases